# VBA: compare two strings logic and return true or false

Tags: string, vba, logic

I want to compare two strings in a specific way.

Strings are logical sentences made from words, operators("+" = AND, "/" = OR) and brackets.
Each word can be true or false.
There is no particular pattern for a sentence - any combination of words and operators can be given

I need to work out function that will return true or false depending if both compared sentences are the same or not.

Let me evaluate few examples:

Example 1:

```
s1 = "A+B+C"
s2 = "A+B+C"
compare(s1, s2) 'will result True
```

Example 2:

```
s1 = "A+B+C"
s2 = "A+C+B"
compare(s1, s2) 'will result True
```

Example 3:

```
s1 = "(A/B)+C"
s2 = "A/B/C"
compare(s1, s2) 'will result False
```

Example 4:

```
s1 = "(A/B)+C"
s2 = "A/(B+C)"
compare(s1, s2) 'will result False
```

Example 5:

```
s1 = "(B/A)+(B/C)"
s2 = "(C/B)+(B/A)"
compare(s1, s2) 'will result True
```

Example 6:

```
s1 = "A+B"
s2 = "A+W"
compare(s1, s2) 'will result False
```

Example 7:

```
s1 = "A/B+C"
s2 = "A/(B+C)"
compare(s1, s2) 'will result False
```

Example 8:

```
s1 = "A/B+C"
s2 = "(A/B)+C"
compare(s1, s2) 'will result True
```

- Words in sentences in real world are not A, B, C... but more like BRS21A, 4FCCS... can be any string actually made from [a-Z 0-9]
- Any sentence can contain any combination of any words
- Operators are always "/" for OR and/or "+" for AND, or no operator if sentence is single word

Thanks a lot for any tips

Comment: Where are these values `BRS21A, 4FCCS` stored? How do you intend to call the function ? In worksheet or VBA? Also Mathematically everything makes sense except `Example 5`!

Comment: They are stored in vba variables but as a part of the string, not as individual variables e.g. "BRS21A/4FCCS" or "BRS21A" or "4FCCS+BRS21A" - just a few examples. I want to retrieve function results in further VBA operations i.e. if compare(s1,s2) = True then...

Comment: Sounds like you will need to implement a little parser. If the set of words is fixed, you could try assigning a number to each word and calculate the result of the equation, e.g. A = 1024 and B = 2048, then by calculating A + B = 3072 = B + A. The numbers must ideally be chosen that your AND/OR calculations affect different bits.

Comment: A, B, BRS21A, ANYTHING can only be True or False. Sets of words isn't fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do a two-step approach inside the compare function. First, I'd replace each word with a number. Second, I'd evaluate the formula to see whether results are equal for both inputs.

Partly pseudo-code:

```
Function compare(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Boolean
    compare = parseAndEvaluate(s1) = parseAndEvaluate(s2)
End Function

Function parseAndEvaluate(str As String) As Long
    ' parse() needs to be implemented
    For Each charOrWord in parse(str)
        Select Case charOrWord
            Case "+", "/", "(", ")":
                parsedStr = parsedStr + charOrWord
            Case Else:
                ' map() needs to be implemented
                parsedStr = parsedStr + map(charOrWord)
        End Select
    Next

    parseAndEvaluate = Application.Evaluate(parsedStr)
End Function
```

The `map()` function could also be some kind of dictionary, assigning a new number (such as 1024, 2048, ...) to new words and mapping previously used words to the previously returned number.

The `parse()` function will read in the string and split at word boundaries.

If your operations `+` and `/` are more difficult, you'll need a slightly more complex parsing code, writing `OR(..., ...)` or `AND(..., ...)` into the string handed to `Application.Evaluate`.